# "Fetch vote count" on a review audit immediately reveals it

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits

I'm reviewing Stack Overflow on my 5.5" Android phone. (yes I'm adding this information because that's how I spot this bug)

I just came across a bad post in FP and was about to vote it down. Because I'm using my phone in portrait mode, the UI is rather small and I accidentally tapped the vote number, which is the action for fetching vote count (show V+ and V- separately). It then shows a red box saying "Vote count on deleted post is not available". I immediately realized it's an audit, and gave it a random flag.

The result doesn't matter because I had already decided to vote it down, but isn't this setting too obvious? I can always click on fetch vote count to determine if it's an audit.

Comment: If anyone can provide an example on revealing a **positive** review audit by fetching vote count, please add it here. Thank you.

Comment: There are several such actions that can reveal an audit - depending on the audit and the post it's possible you can't comment or you can't edit. The point of an audit is to check if you're paying attention. A roboreviewer is unlikely to comment or check the vote split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My impression is that audits are meant to catch people who just click one button ("Looks good" or whatever) as fast as they can, so they can get 20 reviews "done" in a minute or so. The type of people who would do that are generally not even going to spend a few seconds to click the vote count. Sure, it is a possibility, but IMO it's not common enough to be a problem.

Additionally, if a user does appear to be gaming this to bypass the audits, a moderator can manually ban them.

Comment: Good idea stating this.