# Viewing vote counts while reviewing immediately unmasks review audits

Tags: feature-request, review, privileges, review-audits, vote-count

Assume you're performing a review of either a *First post* or *Late answer* (on any SE site where audit reviews are enabled). If you do have the [Established Users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege on that site, you can also "*view the vote counts*" for the post you're reviewing.

**If the post is NOT an audit review**, you'll see the vote counts which will look similar to this image (taken from the above link):

[image]

**If the post is an audit review**, then either of the following will happen:

- for a ***high quality post***, as in [this review](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/766371) I completed today, you'll see the actual vote counts, which are typically lots of upvotes, and hardly any (quite often none) downvotes.
- for a ***low quality post***, you will NOT see the actual vote counts, but instead you'll get a (red) popup message with "*This post has been deleted.*".

So think about this ... if during any First Posts or Late Answers review, all such privileged user does is to *view the vote counts* (without even looking at the title of the post, or the actual post content), any review audit is revealed by doing so.

Unless I am missing something, I doubt this is part of the intended design of "review audits". And therefore it seems to me that a possible remedy could be that in the First Posts and Late Answers review queues, the "*view the vote counts*" facility should be disabled for any privileged users. And even though another remedy could be to fail the audit if a user attempts to check the vote counts, I'd prefer to just disable this facility during reviews.

Note: some reasons why I think this question is different from  '["Fetch vote count" on a review audit immediately reveals it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304166/286501)':

- that question doesn't say anything about high quality posts ... for which a similar issue exists.
- it only mentions the First Posts queue, while for Late Answers as well as Triage on Stack Overflow the same issue exists, and potentially the same is true for the other review queues.
- it is about Stack Overflow, while my question is about "any SE site where audit reviews are enabled".

I haven't had an opportunity yet to double check if a similar scenario applies to any of the other review queues (Low Quality Posts, etc), because I don't have enough rep to access those queues yet on sites with audits, and on the sites I do, review audits are disabled. Though I think I can already predict the results of such similar scenarios also (i.e.: same issue).

Comment: You are missing something: everything in the answer to the other post applies here as well.

Comment: I find it odd that the other question was marked as a duplicate of this one—when it actually has an answer that's useful here. What that the intended duplicate direction?

Comment: @JasonBassford Please see the bullets in this question where it explains how it's different.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288046/839601)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog So—what you're saying is that the first two comments here are not relevant.