# Failing Review Audit because I added a comment that it was a duplicate post

Tags: support, review-audits

I reviewed a post in the Super User First Post queue and thought it sounded familiar.  I searched for the subject and found a previous post with the same question.  I then  added a comment recommending they search for previous questions and gave them a link to the duplicate question and answers.  Since the audit changed the name of the user, there was no way for me to know otherwise.  So why would I fail then?

[image: Post Review image]

Comment: According to [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work), identifying a "good" post as being an exact duplicate of an earlier, highly-voted post is a common reason for failing an audit. However, it also says that if you encounter a bad audit, you should post it on the *per-site* meta, [Meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com), not here.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog: There's nothing wrong with the selection of that post for an audit, so it should not be reported. The problem is entirely with the audit system that misinterprets appropriate actions as inappropriate ones. [That's a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188885/clicking-add-comment-fails-review-audit), and not something a per-site meta can help with at all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Actually, it can. If the user ended up getting banned from reviewing as a result of failing this audit, local moderators can lift the ban. Also, the FAQ says that bad audits should be reported on the per-site meta.

Comment: What review action did you select? And just to clarify since it's not entirely explicit in your question, the question that you thought it was a duplicate of was the very question presented in the audit just with the user's name changed?

Comment: Also @ReyJuna the next time you find something in review that could be a duplicate, you should use the duplicate flagging UI. If the post is a real review, once you flag, the system will automatically post a comment on your behalf saying "Possible duplicate of", which you can edit. Also, if you search in the duplicate flagging UI and can't find the duplicate there, it means the post itself is being shown as an audit and you should positively review it.

Comment: I've never been tempted to audit anything. (I think I looked at one once out of curiosity and then abandoned it.) Instead, I've simply waited for my reputation to be sufficient for actual close votes. (Or, prior to that, I've raised the odd flag.) But it's because of the kind of problem raised here that I think the audit process is flawed. That and the fact that it presupposes some kind of objective judgment when things don't work like that in reality. Votes to close are based on a subjective consensus. And nobody should be told how or why to upvote or downvote.

Comment: @JasonBassford You might be interested in [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188885/clicking-add-comment-fails-review-audit). Also, I think that for known-good FP question audits, the question itself should show in the duplicate closure option, and if someone tries to flag or vote to close it as a duplicate of that, it should pass the audit.

Comment: Also, comments are disabled in the LQ queue; it may be worth disabling them in the other queues as well?

Comment: The scenario described in this question, seems to me similar to **bungee jumping without knowing if the rope is NOT too long**. Because participating in the review process, puts you at risk to fail audit reviews (e.g due to bugs mentioned in prior comments). So for as long such bugs are not fixed, I recommend to [Established users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) to use the safety belt described in [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311570/286501) I posted before ...

Comment: @Alex if you leave a comment on a "good" audit post from review, you'll fail the audit.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Or, as an alternative, [this user script](https://github.com/normalhuman/AuditDetector).

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog: The point is, this *isn't* a bad audit *post*. It's *yet another example of exactly the same bug in the system*. Exactly the same thing could happen with *any* known-good audit. It's nonsensical to say "well report them all!" Now, a bad ban, sure, the mods need to know about that, but that doesn't need to go on meta either. Custom flag a post somewhere.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yeah, I feel that the resolution of this post as a duplicate of the post which reports that bug is correct.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog, I'm not aware of the "duplicate flagging UI".  Is that something that I should learned about in one of the tours?

Comment: If you believe a question is a duplicate of another, you can flag it by clicking "flag" then "duplicate". This will present a search box where you can search for a potential duplicate. Once you cast your flag, it will be reviewed by users who have the ability to close posts, and will automatically post a comment with a link to the post you selected.

Comment: @Alex, I added the comment and then clicked that I was complete.  It was in the First Posts queue with a different name and low reputation that seemed appropriate for a new user.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog Thanks, I'll try that next time.

Comment: Why would leaving a comment be considered a negative thing?

Comment: @Alex - In this case the commentary submitted implied a duplicate question existed already but without actually flagging or linking to said duplicate.  [The author recommended they search for previous questions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13524/failing-review-audit-because-i-added-a-comment-that-it-was-a-duplicate-post), in this case, the audit system actually worked.  Submitting a comment telling somebody they should perform a search isn’t helpful, when there, wasn’t anything wrong with the question

Comment: @Ramhound That sounds more like it didn’t work but just happened to get lucky that in this case the comment was unnecessary.

Comment: @Ramhound, actually I did provide a link to the duplicate in the comment, but admittedly I didn't flag it as I thought that flagging was for serious problems.

Comment: Your not able to vote to close, only reason flagging it as a duplicate is appropriate

Comment: @Ramhound, I understand now, but when I hovered over the Flag link it pops up "flag this post for serious problems or moderator attention".  I didn't realize that that description included flagging as duplicate.  I interpreted it to mean more like abusive language.